# Making a C# console application interact with wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, console

If this is possible, I would like to make in C# a wpf application that has a console window in it.  Also, I would like to have the console interact with the WPF form so that if you are complete with a console activity it can tell the wpf application and close.  I guess this would be a basic inheritance program, but with a console/simulated console included.

Comment: What have you tried? I'm not sure if there's a way to add direct command console support into the application directly, but you could add a textbox and parse it out to a script file and execute it maybe?

Comment: Can you have a custom console window? If so, build one and put it in the WPF app. If you want the windows console (cmd.exe), then @GustavoF's answer below is probably best. As nice has it sounds opening a console with the WPF has too many warts IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something called interprocess communication.

There is a [lot of ways of do that](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/local-machine-interprocess-communication-with-net), but the easiest is the [Named Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) IMHO.

Comment: I was going to make a console game that you get a different graphic with each level on the outside (WPF).  That was the plan, because the console is so easy to program in.  Maybe I am asking the wrong question, how can I make a console-like application with wpf?  I am reviewing your comments.  Thank you!

Comment: WPF Text Input Controls - inside a TextBox.  I think this is what I am aiming for